# I want to write to a new file not append for every iteration

Tags: python, file, append

I want to create a new file for each iteration, but I'm not able to do so. I'm only able to update the same old file, how could I solve this?

The other more basic question what is "" function in file.write("".)?
I have tried with "w" but it still doesn't work..

Here is my code:

```
 def write_to_file(self,lista): 
    file=open("file.txt","a") 
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("".join(str(lista)))
    file.close()
```

Comment: what the content of ur lista???

Comment: ©Hackaholic, I have two different lists, one of them is [str(area),str(sun digit)], and the other one is just ["Format: Area, Sundigit"]

Answer (score 2):

The "a" in open(path, "a") means append. If you want to open a new file, use "w". This would also overwrite any old file with this name.

If you want to stick with "a" you can provide also the path to the file, and prevent that other files are overwritten later. But you have to choose a different name then.

```
def write_to_file(path, lista):
    f = open(path,"a")
    f.write("something")
    f.close()
```

As for the join:

"x".join(["a","b","c"]) results in "axbxc"

It concatenates the list using the "x" (in your case an empty string "") as separators between each element.

Comment: It doesn't work with "w"... ©Godrebh

Comment: What is the error message if you try it with "w"?

Comment: @Godbreh If I use "w" I create a file but only with one row of my table, but if I use append then I get all of the rows and I create a proper table

Comment: Ok, I think you open the file every time within a loop and thus delete everything, which is already inside it. Open it outside the loop. And close it afterwards.

Comment: But then I get a global variable? ©Godrebh, I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do this:

```
def write_to_file(self, lista, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w+') as file: # filename should be a String here
        file.write('\n')
        file.write(''.join(str(lista)))
```

The use of `with` statement is safer and much easier than `open` and `close` because it does it all alone when your treatment on the file is over.

This will create a new file each time you call the function.

I added the `filename` parameter because if you would have left the `'file.txt'` string in your statement it would have overwritten it each time you would have called the function and I guess this is not what you want...

**EDIT**

Reading your comments, I'm starting to understand your problem, my guess is you want to write a list of lists in your file, here is what you could do:

```
def write_to_file(self, main_list, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w+') as file:
        for lista in main_list:
            file.write('\n')
            file.write(''.join(str(lista)))
```

This will create a new file, iterate through your list of lists and write each list from the main one in the file.

Comment: Still doesn't work.. ©Oscar

Comment: What is the error message you get when using this ? @Pellegrino

Comment: @Pellegrino How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Cause when I run the program, I only get one line, instead of getting all the lines from a table. ©PeterWood

Comment: @Pellegrino It is normal for you to get one line with this code, if you call the function in a `for` loop, it will erase the old `lista` content from the file and replace it with the new `lista` content, if you want to write multiple lines in your file I suggest using a `for` loop in the `with` statement.

Comment: @Pellegrino you need to use an @ symbol not a © to send messages to people.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
file=open("file.txt","w") 
def write_to_file(self,lista): 
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("".join(str(lista)))
file.close()
```

it works fine:

```
>>> file = open('ll.txt','w')
>>> def f(s):
...     file.write(s)
... 
>>> f("hello")
>>> file.close()
```

Comment: ©Hackaholic, but then I get a global variabel..

Comment: yea you will get a global variable, but if you will open in write mode it will overwrite file

Comment: is it possible to avoid that? ©Hackaholic ??

Comment: Do you know the difference between ""join(str(lista) and without the "" btw??? @Hackaholic

Comment: @Pellegrino you are confused, how exectly you want to do, what is your expected input and what is your expected output, edit your post to provide proper infromation